# echoed script doesn't start

Tags: javascript, php, html, sql

I am creating a forum. The problem occurs when I try to echo out a comment on a post. The script doesn't seem to do anything.

```php
if($result->num_rows>0){
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){

        $username=$row['username'];
        $file=$row['file'];
        $text=$row['text'];
        $date=$row['date'];
        $postId=$row['postId'];
        $commentOn=$row['commentOn'];

        if($commentOn == 0){
            echo'
            <li>   
                                <div class="comment">
                                    <p><am>+</am>'.$username.'</a><em>'.$date.'</em> _ #'.$postId.'</p>
                                        <div>
                                        <img src='.$file.'>
                                            <p>'.$text.'</p>
                                            <p><Button>upvote</Button><Button>downvote</Button><form action="upload2.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" accept-charset="utf-8">
                                                        <textarea name="text" cols="30" rows="2"></textarea>
                                                        <textarea id="sov" name="postIdr">'.$postId.'</textarea>
                                                        <input type="submit" value="Reply">
                                                    </form><ap>Reply</ap></p>
                                        </div>
                                </div>
                            <div id="h'.$postId.'"></div>

            </li>';
        }else{
            //Here is where the problem area starts
            echo'            <script type="text/javascript"> document.getElementById("h'.$commentOn.'").innerHTML = "
                <ul>
                <li>   
                <div class="comment">
                    <p><am>+</am>'.$username.'</a><em>'.$date.'</em> _ #'.$postId.'</p>
                        <div>
                            <p>'.$text.'</p>
                            <p><Button>upvote</Button><Button>downvote</Button><form action="upload2.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" accept-charset="utf-8">
                                        <textarea name="text" cols="30" rows="2"></textarea>
                                        <textarea id="sov" name="postIdr">'.$postId.'</textarea>
                                        <input type="submit" value="Reply">
                                    </form><ap>Reply</ap></p>
                        </div>
                </div>
            <div id="h'.$postId.'"></div>

</li>
                </ul>
                ";</script>
            ';    }
}
}
?>
```

I don't see how this is wrong. I get no error messages and I see nothing on the webpage

Comment: Javascript strings cant be multi lined unless using back ticks ` or using \ as the last character in each line. You are also using double quotes to denote your js code string but dont escape the double quotes inside the string. You will have errors in the browsers javascript console

Comment: did you check if you have any errors? add this code `ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errprs', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Comment: may be stupid but is $commentOn=0 ???